# Missing categories 2 months before sunset - Migration of Google My Business API

Tags: google-my-business-api

Maybe I am missing something with the current migration of Google MyBusiness API.

We have scripts running on the Google My Business API which will end in April 2022, replaced by several new Business APIs.

The problem is that it's February 8 and some features like reviews, posts, ..., that we use, are still not migrated to the new APIs.

I can't see how we're going to do the migration if they are delivered a few days before the deadline. Unless they are not migrated at all?

Am I the only one with this problem ?

Thanks for any news

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only those parts of the GMB API that have published successors will be deprecated:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/sunset-dates

Neither the review nor the local post methods are marked for deprecation.

Update: the documentation tree also has indicators showing what is and is not deprecated (I added the green squares to signify that those examples are not deprecated yet).

[image]

Comment: I read a lot of time the page you posted in reference, but I don't understand the same thing. I am certainly wrong but there is a sunset date for accounts.locations [API Google My Business version 4.9] on 30/04/2022
And review is part of the accounts.locations category as the name is "accounts.locations.reviews".
So when google says they sunset accounts.locations, a sub part of this category is not concerned ?
Same for accounts.locations.localPosts which is a part of accounts.locations.
Where is the information that these two are not going to be deprecated ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. 
So I misunderstood the signification of the deprecated icon. For me, the icon told us that these parts had already been migratedn and those with no icon had not currently been migrated but will be before the sunset.
Maybe it's me but it's not clear.
It's very strange that Google migrates only some parts to the new APIs.