# Problem finding metrics in the new Google My Business APIs

Tags: google-my-business-api

I am having some issues migrating my Google MY Business API python code.
My original code looks like:

1. Get my accounts:

```
service, flags = sample_tools.init(argv, "mybusiness", "v4", __doc__, __file__,
                                   scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage",
                                   discovery_filename=cfg.discovery_doc_old)
output = service.accounts().list().execute()
accounts = output["accounts"]
```

2. Get my locations name per account with the following call:

```
self.service.accounts().locations().list(parent=account['name']).execute()
```

3. For each location I get my insights report with the following call:

```
service.accounts().locations().reportInsights(name=self.account, body=body).execute()
```

Now since these calls are going to be deprecated, I need to update this code to the new Business APis. So far I managed to reproduce step 1 & 2 of my old code:

1. Get my accounts (using the my business account management api):

```
service, flags = sample_tools.init(argv, "mybusinessaccountmanagement", "v1", __doc__, __file__,
                                       scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage",
                                       discovery_filename=cfg.discovery_doc_new)

output = self.service.accounts().list().execute()
accounts = output["accounts"]
```

2. Get my location (using my business business information api):

```
service, flags = sample_tools.init(argv, "mybusinessbusinessinformation", "v1", __doc__, __file__,
                                       scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage",
                                       discovery_filename=cfg.discovery_doc_gmb_info)
output = service.accounts().locations().list(parent=self.accounts[0]['name'],
                                                          readMask='name',
                                                          ).execute()
locations = output['locations']
```

Now I am missing the equivalent to the old

```
reportInsights(name=self.account, body=body).execute()
```

I haven't found anywhere some similar. I thought maybe I need to add it as the readmask, but also could find any documentation. I basically want to get the values of these metrics for each location using one of the new APIs:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/Metric

I already went through this tutorial, even though I prefer using the client libraries:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup
but it doesn't tell me where to find these metrics.

I have also tried the same structure as in the old API but I get the error message:

> AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'reportInsights'

Can someone help me with this? I am quite new to the Google APIs and maybe there is something obvious I missing out :/

Thanks a lot,
Rafael

Comment: TLDR: they are not deprecated. I believe this question will answer you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71026412/missing-categories-2-months-before-sunset-migration-of-google-my-business-api.

Answer (score 0):

As @devinthemaking has stated correctly, the `reportInsights` method is not deprecated and does not have a successor method yet.

The list of deprecated methods can be found here: [Deprecation schedule](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/sunset-dates)